# Elasticsearch structure to add additional keys to an existing key value pair

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, opensearch

I have data that I store in Elasticsearch currently in the format:

```
{
  "<dynamic key>": "<value>"
},
...
```

The data represents tags within documents and both the key and value are dynamic based on what the user has tagged.

I now want to store a couple of additional fields which directly relate to the same data. What I did was convert the mapping from a keyword field to a nested field and then structured my data like this:

```
{
  "<dynamic key>": {
    "value": "<value>",
    "text": "<some text>",
    "text_hash": "<some hash>"
  },
  ...
}
```

As it stands there are a few hundred different elements a user can tag and so the mapping can grow to around that size. When I started populating it I hit a nested field limit. You can override it using the "index.mapping.nested_fields.limit" setting however the docstring for that setting implies that changing it may be indicative of a poorly designed mapping setup so I am wondering if I am going about this in the wrong way and there is a more correct way to store several pieces of data against a given key?

The structure of my index mapping using the nested layout is:

```
"index_name": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "date_detection": false,
            "numeric_detection": false,
            "properties": {
                "file_id": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "file_properties": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "property_name_1": {
                            "type": "nested",
                            "properties": {
                                "text": {
                                    "type": "text",
                                    "analyzer": "english"
                                },
                                "text_hash": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "null_value": "NULL"
                                },
                                "file_value": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "null_value": "NULL"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        ...
                    }
                },
                "file_text": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1683101455144",
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "rgrfgqwdewf3464dwd",
                "version": {
                    "created": "563728185"
                },
                "provided_name": "index_name"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Previously it was of course much flatter, as I was only storing a basic key, value pair. It feels like with this new setup, if I introduce several hundred tags it will make it bloated and inefficient.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: You're correct in highlighting `index.mapping.nested_fields.limit` as an issue. In general, Elastic/OpenSearch indices perform better with a set "pool" of fields. Some documents may have 100 fields, and others may only have 5, however, it's advised that fields/keys are unchanging (e.g. no dynamic values). Perhaps a list of tags where each entry is a dict would meet your needs.